# bootstrap 3 alert not sliding up after 3 seconds

Tags: php, jquery, twitter-bootstrap-3

I'm showing a success alert to the user that his email was sent successfully to me, And I want this alert to `.slideUp()` after 3 seconds.

Here is my code:

```
if ($('.dat-alert').length) {
    setTimeout($(this).slideUp(), 3000);
}
```

I'm printing the alert with php here:

```
if(mail($mail_to, $mail_subject, $mail_body,$header)){
        $mailMessage = '<div class="alert alert-success alert-dismissable dat-alert text-center">';
        $mailMessage.= '<button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="alert" aria-hidden="true">&times;</button>';
        $mailMessage.= 'Gracias por ponerte en contacto. Te responderemos en la brevedad posible.' ;
        $mailMessage.= '</div>';
}
```

However, the alert isn't hiding at all. Anyone has any idea why?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to pass an actual *function* to `setTimeout`, not arbitrary code (unless it's a string, but that's bad).  Just replace this

```
if ($('.dat-alert').length) {
    setTimeout($(this).slideUp(), 3000);
}
```

with this

```
if ($('.dat-alert').length) {
    setTimeout(function(){ $(this).slideUp(); }.bind(this), 3000);
}
```

---

EDIT - it seems from your comment that `this` isn't what it should be.  Without seeing more code I can't be certain, but regardless, try replacing `this` with a proper selector, something like:

```
if ($('.dat-alert').length) {
    setTimeout(function(){ $('.dat-alert:first').slideUp(); }, 3000);
}
```

Comment: thanks for the answer, but it's still not sliding up :s

Comment: I'm wrapping this `if()` inside the common `$(document).ready()`

Comment: What BlackSheep said was correct, and I did exactly what you did Adam. Thanks to both! It works now.